# How to insert json into mysql using node js?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

```
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
var length;
var affiliate = require('flipkart-affiliate');
var url = require('url');
var moment=require('moment');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var body;
var getUrl;
var product;
var offer;
var offer1;
var offer2;
var offer3;
var test1;
var test2;
var test3;
var title=[];
var description=[];
var startTime=[];
var endTime=[];
var json={};
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'coupontest'
});
var client = affiliate.createClient({
    FkAffId: 'anandhkum',
    FkAffToken: 'eb030998c556443087d3b1a27ac569d0',
    responseType: 'json'
});
client.getCategoryFeed({
    trackingId: 'anandhkum'
}, function(err, result,getUrl){
    if(!err){
        body=JSON.parse(result);
        getUrl=body.apiGroups.affiliate.apiListings.food_nutrition.availableVariants["v1.1.0"].get;
        client.getProductsFeed({
            url: getUrl
        }, function(err, result){
            if(!err){

            }else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
});
app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    client.getAllOffers(null,function(err, resp) {
        if (!err) {
            offer = JSON.parse(resp);
            test1 = offer.allOffersList.length;
            res.send(offer);
            for(var i=0;i<test1;i++){
                description[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].description;
                startTime[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].startTime;
                endTime[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].endTime;
            }
            var stmt = "INSERT INTO offers(description,start_time,end_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            connection.query(stmt, [description,startTime,endTime], function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err.message;
                console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening to port 3000");
```

the code is about getting the offer details as json data from flipkart.com and store it into the mysql table.

But I'm getting the error

throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I tried using many sql syntax but it's showing the above error

Can anyone help me on solving the above error?

Comment: you are trying to insert a array ( e.g startTime) into a table . can you try a single value . Try moving insert statement inside for loop ?

Comment: Please reduce your code example to a minimum in order to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way, as I can see you want to insert multiple result at once so need to pass an array **values** which I have made in following query also the error **"ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW"** is due to incorrect no of **?** that you were passing in the query as you need to insert multiple no of rows so you need to make sure you get correct **?** count.

```
     var queryString = "";
            var insertString = "(?,?,?),";
         var values = [];
         for(var i=0;i<test1;i++){
                            description[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].description;
                            startTime[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].startTime;
                            endTime[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].endTime;
values.push(description[i],startTime[i],endTime[i]);
        queryString = queryString + insertString;
                        }
        queryString = queryString.substring(0, queryString.length - 1); // is used to remove last ',' which will get inserted while we are creating queryString 
                        var stmt = "INSERT INTO offers(description,start_time,end_time) VALUES " + queryString ;
                        connection.query(stmt,values, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) throw err.message;
                            console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
                        });
```